# WP_Query To Display Product Of Brand On Taxonomy Page

Tags: php, wp-query, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to print all products of a brand on a taxonomy page.

I find the wp_querry but i cant print the current brand name of the brand to show all products in this page.

What to put on terms array to print the current page brand name?

```
// get products
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query'      => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'pwb-brand',
          'field'    => 'name',
          'terms'    => array ('NAME?????')
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    endwhile;
} else {
    echo __( 'not found anyhting.' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: so you are on a taxonomy archive page, lets say, url/pwb-brand/pwb-brand-x, correct? than the default wordpress query should handle the query by itself..? if you need to rund your own query, consider using `get_queried_object()` to get the `query_vars`. speaking of query vars, you registered your custom taxonomy to poplulate query vars, correct..?

Comment: If you're on a taxonomy archive for the pwb-brand already then why are you creating a custom query and loop? Is this because you wanted to add `posts_per_page` set to `-1` but instead of modifying the main query, you replaced it, leading to this problem? Or modify the post types fetched? Is there a particular reason you didn't ask about the original problem instead? This looks like you're asking for a solution to a problem with a solution to a problem, an XY problem

Comment: @TomJNowell I wanna use the `posts_per_page` to `-1` to print all the products of this brand.

Comment: That can be done without any of this, but keep in mind that too many posts and the page will never finish loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the queried object, but that still leaves the unmentioned problem that you're discarding the main query and doing a second one, making the page at a minimum 2x slower. Pagination is also broken by this.

You may have seen people warn you against using `query_posts`, this is why, using `WP_Query` the same way is just recreating the insides of that function.

#### Doing it With Filters and Actions

Instead, use the `pre_get_posts` action to modify the main post request before WP goes to the database.

e.g. here is an example that excludes the category with id `1` from the homepage:

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

So instead, lets replace the check with something like this:

```
if ( $query->is_tax( 'pwb-brand' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
```

And set the `posts_per_page` value, e.g.

```
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
```

#### Caveats

By setting this to `-1` the worst case scenario has gotten significantly worse, and there is now no upper limit on how slow or expensive this page will be. So much slow, you may run out of execution time, or memory trying to display it.

You might think "But there's only 50 products that'll never happen", to which I would say, set a stupidly high number you never expect to hit, but never `-1`/everything.

Alternatives include:

- pagination
- lazy loading
- infinite scroll

Some people display everything because they want to be able to do `ctrl+f` and find a product easily, but this can be done with a search box and a hidden input with the name `post_type` and the value `product`, and a second that sets the taxonomy to `pwb-brand`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the solution. The products its not so many and i have activate cache and lazy loading to avoid increase of cpu and memory

Comment: Thanks, but do put in a stupidly high number, e.g. 200 or even 500. If the customer pivots in the future or accidentally duplicates things a lot, at least the page won't fall over, and if the database has to do all that work, it might make the server become unresponsive, so it's covering your bases